# Photoshop 2020: "Error 1302: No such element"

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

This script renames layers but in Photoshop 2020 I get the above error for line 20:

> **Error 1302: No such element**
> **Line: 20**
> **->   if (layernames[currentLayer.name]) {**

The layers are definitely in the document so I'm struggling to identify what the problem is. Here is the script below:

```
// JavaScript Document
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// name indexed object
var layernames = {
 'Products':'Working',
 'Product':'Working',
 'Notes':'Note',
 'Background color':'Background Colour',
 'White background':'White Background'
};

// loop through all layers
for (var i = 0; i < doc.layers.length; i++)
{

 //Set up Variable to access layer name
 var currentLayer = app.activeDocument.layers;

 if (layernames[currentLayer.name]) {
     currentLayer.name = layernames[currentLayer.name];
 }
}
```

Comment: You're assigning `currentLayer` to an array of layers, not a layer. Should be something like `doc.activeLayer = doc.layers[i]; currentLayer = doc.activeLayer`

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Yes! Thank you so much. You're a prince among men!

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Is there any way for it to iterate through layers within folders? At the moment it only works on independent layer names or folder names but not layers within folders..

Comment: You can do that through DOM or Action Manager: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52043430/3833874

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy - Using Recursion as per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373549/photoshop-renaming-script-does-not-iterate-through-layers-within-folders/63394399#63394399) is optimal for such as task.

Comment: @RobC define 'optimal'? Using AM to traverse the layers stack is much faster than selecting all layers one by one using DOM. However in this particular example the difference won't be too noticeable (my AM version was only about 1.5x faster) because AM command for renaming only works on active layer — so I have to select layers before renaming anyway

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy - Yes, your point is moot in this instance. I (like many others) consider human readable code and well documented design patterns such as Recursion key factors towards "optimal" code. Sure, AM code (typically machine generated code via the ScriptListener plugin) may provide some micro optimization regarding time duration - but often seen (by humans) as difficult to comprehend/reason with,